# Метод groups.getById вконтакте не возвращает поля start_date, finish_date

Tags: vkontakte-api

Собственно, код:

```
    window.onload = function() {
        VK.init({
            apiId: id приложения
        });
    }

    $('#vk_link').on('change', function () {
        var link = $(this).val();
        var group_id = link.substr(link.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        VK.Api.call('groups.getById', {
            access_token: 'здесь токен',
            group_id: group_id,
            group_ids: group_id,
            fields: "description, place, start_date, finish_date"
        }, function(result){
            console.log(result);
        });
    });
```

В результате возвращаются совсем другие поля, не те, что запрашивались (кроме описания). Что здесь не так?

Answer (score 0):

Из [документации](https://vk.com/dev/objects/group_2?f=3.%2B%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%2B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%2BP-W):

> для встреч содержат время начала и окончания встречи в формате
>   unixtime. Для публичных страниц содержит только start_date — дата
>   основания в формате YYYYMMDD.

Но раз вы говорите что вы и `start_date` не получаете, тогда скорее всего у вашего токена нет прав доступа для `groups`.

UPD. Ещё заметил что у групп не выводит `start_date`, у публичных страниц показывает, видимо это работает так API, проверил на 10 группах и пабликах.

Comment: Для `start_date` не требуется право доступа `groups`. Т.е. для него должен подходить сервисный ключ моего приложения, который я использую. Не так?

Comment: @DotCom обновил ответ, проблема в типе группы как я понял